# MultiIndex Dataframe compare one index raw against others

Tags: python, pandas, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a dataframe with lists as values.

```
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["file1", "file2", "file3"], ["a", "b"]])
index.names = ['file', 'name']
data = [
    [[1,1],[0,0]],
    [[],[]],
    [[2,2,2],[7]],
    [[],[]],
    [[1],[4, 4]],    
    [[],[]],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df
```

df

```
                col1    col2
file    name        
file1   a      [1, 1]   [0, 0]
        b       []      []
file2   a    [2, 2, 2]  [7]
        b       []      []
file3   a       [1]     [4, 4]
        b       []      []
```

I want to group by `name` and run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (`scipy.stats.ks_2samp`) between each row and a concatenation of others rows. Example for name `a`. `{file1,a}` == `[1,1]`. Concatenation of others `{file2,a}` + `{file3,a}` == `[2,2,2]` + `[1]` == `[2,2,2,1]`. KStest between them is `stats.ks_2samp([1,1], [2,2,2,1])` == `0.75`.
How can I get the expected result below (done it by hand manually)?

```
               col1     col2
file    name        
file1   a       0.75    1.0
        b       NaN     NaN
file2   a       1.0     1.0
        b       NaN     NaN
file3   a       0.6     0.66
        b       NaN     NaN
```

I'm sorry if this is too adhoc question.

Below is my attempt. I couldn't figure out how elegantly exclude the target row from other rows.

```
df.groupby(['name']).apply(
    lambda per_name_df: per_name_df.apply(
        lambda per_column: per_column.apply(
            lambda cell: stats.ks_2samp(cell, np.concatenate(per_column.to_numpy())) if cell else cell)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... test between a single row and a concatenation of others rows

as you didn't specify which rows in particular, I'll give you an example to test between first row and all remaining rows:

```
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
def ks(a, b):
    b = [el for li in b for el in li]
    if a and b:
        return ks_2samp(a, b)[0]

df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('name')).col1.apply(lambda x: ks(x[0],x[1:].to_list()))
```

Result:

```
name
a    0.75
b     NaN
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

**Update for edited question**:

> ... test between each row and a concatenation of others rows

```
def ks_all(a):
    a = a.to_list()
    return [ks(a[i],a[:i]+a[i+1:]) for i in range(0,len(a))]

df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('name')).transform(ks_all)
```

Result:

```
            col1      col2
file  name                
file1 a     0.75  1.000000
      b      NaN       NaN
file2 a     1.00  1.000000
      b      NaN       NaN
file3 a     0.60  0.666667
      b      NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thank for such quick response. I've fixed `df` and clarified my question better.

Comment: I've updated my question with my attempt. What do you think of that?

Comment: your attempt gives different (and I think not the intended) results, as the second parameter of `ks_2samp` includes the first parameter: for instance for the first row of col1 you test `ks_2samp([1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1])` whereas - as per your description - it should be `ks_2samp([1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 1])`. (further 'name' is not a column but part of the index, so you're code doesn't run as is).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I just thought that it can be improved somehow to exclude the target row.